# Creating Video from Images with OpenCV in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opencv

Is there any way to create a video from array of images with OpenCV framework in iPhone?
Please help me.I do not know detail information about OpenCV framework.Thanx in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using VideoCapture to capture from the sequence of images ? check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131770/creating-video-from-images-with-opencv-2-4-1-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use OpenCV?

The `AVFoundation` framework supports this. Take a look at - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3742212/384155

If you need to use OpenCV only, try http://myopencv.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/creating-your-own-videos-in-opencv/

Comment: Thanx for reply.Video which is created via AVFoundation is not running smoothly.So,I am looking for a library or framework which helps me in video editing functionality.I think OpenCV can help me